# CodeIgniter, Get data from mysql without looping .How to solve it?

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3

i created a script for e-commerce but i have a promblem.

Script for models

```
function _cek($from_dat,$where_dat,$limit=null){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($from_dat);
    $this->db->where($where_dat);
    if($limit){
        $this->db->limit($limit);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Script for controller

```
$dat = array();
            $dat = $this->user_mod->_ambil("voucher",$data_where);
            print_r($dat['0']);
            $data_account = $dat;echo "error".$i;$i++;
            while($dat){
                $datas_nominal = $dat->nominal;
                echo $datas_nominal;
            }
            $saldo = $dat['nominal'];echo "error".$i;$i++;
            $status = $dat['status'];echo "error".$i;$i++;
            echo "error".$i;$i++;
            echo $status;
            if($status == 0){
                echo $status;
                //redirect("home/pay/invalid/2");echo "error".$i;$i++;
            }
```

i get data from database use it

```
$dat = $this->user_mod->_ambil("voucher",$data_where);
            print_r($dat['0']);
            $data_account = $dat;echo "error".$i;$i++;
            $saldo = $dat['nominal'];echo "error".$i;$i++;
            $status = $dat['status'];echo "error".$i;$i++;
```

and i get notice undefined index nominal and undefined index status.
for full script see at http://pastebin.com/AEj2HFhZ

Comment: on which file and which file do you get that error ?

Comment: i get error at file controller....